# RESTful MongoDB with Nodejs example needed

Tags: rest, mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to use MongoDB with REST interface on NodeJS express and I'm puzzled.
I've read about REST all day and I just cannot grasp it.

Let's say I have an untrusted (browser) client.
The untrusted client calls "GET /somecollection", the server verifies the client permissions and then calls "GET /somecollection" on the database itself?

Comment: The question is: how do you define REST routes on server side? preferably when using MongoDB and Nodejs. The documentation is very sparse.

Comment: is the answer provided below what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this project very helpful: https://github.com/pminnieur/entropy.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a Restful library with an example:
https://github.com/Empeeric/jest